# Find Lowest Sum of "x" Consecutive Numbers in A List

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to find the lowest sum of ***x*** consecutive numbers in a column of 91 numbers (column A, for example). For example, if ***x*** is 30, I want to find the lowest sum of 30 consecutive numbers in the 91 number column. I will need to do this calculation for each value of ***x*** between 30 and 78.

The brute force, non-VBA approach would look something like this for the case where ***x*** = 30:

```
=MIN(SUM(A1:A30),SUM(A2:A31),SUM(A3:32),...,SUM(A62:A91))
```

For the case where ***x*** = 78, this non-VBA approach would look like this:

```
=MIN(SUM(A1:A78),SUM(A2:A79),SUM(A3:A80),...,SUM(A14:A91))
```

I have 20 columns (each with 91 numbers) that I need to apply this function to, so the column needs to be a variable as well. My guess is that we would define a function with a ***range length*** input (i.e. ***x***) and a ***column*** input.

I don't have much experience with VBA syntax. Can you guys/gals help me formulate something?

I would normally try to solve this myself (I tried the Excel brute force way then tried making my own UDF but I didn't know where to start).

Comment: This almost looks like a homework assignment. This site is to help people with specific issues that they may be having with otherwise working code, not to generate a whole program for you.  I would google looping and VBA, perhaps here: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html and then ranges in vba, perhaps here: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/range-object.html. Then, try to make your macro do something and if you have an issue, post about the specific issue you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you require VBA?

It's possible to do this with an "array formula", e.g. if your "x" value is in cell `Z1` you can use this formula

`=MIN(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1:A91,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(A1:A91)-Z1+1)),0,Z1)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: This is awesome!!! Thank you. It took me a while to understand, but I think I finally got it. One thing though: shouldn't the "rows" argument in the OFFSET formula be: ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(A1:A91)-Z1+1)) **MINUS 1**? I want the possible consecutive formulas to start at row reference 0 relative to the start of the list (without the *minus 1*, I think the sums in the array start a row below the first item in the list). Thank you for your help, I learned a lot already just trying to decipher this formula.

Comment: Yes, you are right, apologies, I missed out the -1, otherwise the first sum will start with A2 - of course using COUNT also pre-supposes that the range is fully populated with numbers

Comment: No worries at all! And yes, regarding COUNT, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following *UDF*:

```
Public Function consec(rng As Range, x As Long) As Double
    Dim r As Range, i As Long, mymin As Double, temp As Double
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    i = 1
    Set r = rng(i).Resize(x, 1)
    mymin = wf.Sum(r)
    For i = 2 To rng.Count - x + 1
        Set r = rng(i).Resize(x, 1)
        temp = wf.Sum(r)
        If temp < mymin Then
            mymin = temp
        End If
    Next i
    consec = mymin
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using barry houdini's answer for the project, but I'm using this as VBA learning experience.

Comment: @wesleybankston  I agree that barry's solution is better.